# Haskell: No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='

Tags: haskell

```
isPalindrome :: [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome xs = case xs of 
                        [] -> True 
                        [x] -> True
                        a -> (last a) == (head a) && (isPalindrome (drop 1 (take (length a - 1) a)))

main = do
    print (show (isPalindrome "blaho"))
```

results in

```
No instance for (Eq a)
  arising from a use of `=='
In the first argument of `(&&)', namely `(last a) == (head a)'
In the expression:
  (last a) == (head a)
  && (isPalindrome (drop 1 (take (length a - 1) a)))
In a case alternative:
    a -> (last a) == (head a)
         && (isPalindrome (drop 1 (take (length a - 1) a)))
```

Why is  this error occurring?

Comment: your function assumes `a`s can be compared with `==`, you have to put this info in the type signature.

Comment: Because `(==)` is a member of the `Eq` class. So you can use it only on types that are instances of `Eq`.

Comment: Real world haskell chap 3?  Me too!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're comparing two items of type `a` using `==`. That means `a` can't just be any type - it has to be an instance of `Eq`, as the type of `==` is `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`.

You can fix this by adding an `Eq` constraint on `a` to the type signature of your function:

```
isPalindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

<sub>By the way, there is a much simpler way to implement this function using `reverse`.</sub>

Comment: According to lambdabot, `isPalindrome = reverse >>= (==)` :D

Comment: @FredOverflow Wow, that's crazy obscure. :)

Comment: It uses the monad instance for functions, just like `join (+) 2 = 4`. But `isPalindrome xs = xs == reverse xs` is totally reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

hammar explanation is correct.

Another simple example:

```
nosPrimeiros :: a -> [(a,b)] -> Bool
nosPrimeiros e [] = False
nosPrimeiros e ((x,y):rl) = if (e==x)   then True
                                        else nosPrimeiros e rl
```

The (e==x) will fail for this function signature. You need to replace:

```
nosPrimeiros :: a -> [(a,b)] -> Bool
```

adding an Eq instance for a

```
nosPrimeiros :: Eq => a -> [(a,b)] -> Bool
```

This instantiation is saying that now, **a** has a type that *can be comparable with* and (e==x) will not fail.