# How to pass HTTP request parameter to quickQuery?

Tags: haskell, happstack, hdbc

I'm using Happstack to receive some parameters from an HTTP request then pass these parameters to a function that will retrieve data from the database and return this data in the HTTP response as follow:

```
myFunc :: IO String
myFunc = do r <- look "personId"
            conn <- connectODBC "... my connection string ...";
            vals <- quickQuery conn ("SELECT Name FROM Person where Id = ?") [(toSql r)];
            return (processData vals)

handlers :: ServerPartT IO Response
handlers = do
       x <- liftIO (myFunc);
       decodeBody (defaultBodyPolicy "/tmp/" 0 1000 1000)
       msum [ 
              dir "getData" $ ok $ toResponse x
            , ... other handlers ...
            ]

mainFunc = simpleHTTP nullConf handlers
```

But when I build the above code I get the following error:

> No instance for (HasRqData IO) arising from a use of `look'
>   In a stmt of a 'do' block: r <- look "personId"

After reading questions on similar issues (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154592/haskell-no-instance-for-eq-a-arising-from-a-use-of)) I think I have to include `HasRqData` constraint somewhere, but I couldn't learn where and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have guessed, this is too an issue with monads. There are a [handful](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.5.0.1/docs/Happstack-Server-Monads.html) of them in `happstack` (`HasRqData`, among others), so you may well consider it a complicated case.

Let us begin with the *innocent-looking* [`look`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.5.0.1/docs/Happstack-Server-RqData.html#v:look) function.

```
look :: (Functor m, Monad m, HasRqData m) => String -> m String
```

Indeed, there is a non-trivial constraint `HasRqData`. Let us ask ourselves: [what monads *HaveRqData*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.5.0.1/docs/Happstack-Server-RqData.html#t:HasRqData)? (It so happens that `IO` has not!)

```
class HasRqData m where
...

Instances
    HasRqData RqData         
    (MonadIO m, MonadPlus m) => HasRqData (ServerPartT m)
    ...
```

The other instances are derivative of these first two, so, it looks like we have to consider these two options first.

- The [`RqData`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.5.0.1/docs/Happstack-Server-RqData.html#t:RqData) has limited effects — you can only do `look` and its derivatives, extracting information from the request at hand. As we want to also have other effects — querying the database, for one, — this is not enough for us.
- The `ServerPartT m` is the general form of the same [old friend of ours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48820722/2108477), `ServerPart ≡ ServerPartT IO`. It happens that it also `HasRqData`. This is not a coincidence, but rather an implication of the design of `happstack` — looks like the authors meant us to use this single monad everywhere, unless we need particular granularity. So, let's give it a try.

```
myFunc :: ServerPart String
myFunc = do r <- look "personId"
            return undefined
```

This compiles.

Now, we don't even need to lift `myFunc` in `handlers` — our [previous predicament](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48820722/2108477) solved itself. We will need to lift our access to the database though, by the same [*jar logic*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48822589/2108477) we discussed before.

I believe you can figure the details by yourself. In any case, let me know how it works out!