# Compiler cannot decide the type of the return value of `take` function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to solve [the 99 problems in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10), and for the 4th question, I have first tried such a solution

```
myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength [] = 0
myLength ys = go 1 ys
 where
  go :: Int -> [a] -> Int
  go n xs
   | ( (take n xs) == (take (n+1) xs) ) = n
   | otherwise = go (n+1) xs
```

However, the compiler gives the error:

```
Problem4.hs:10:8: error:
    • No instance for (Eq a1) arising from a use of ‘==’
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a1) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            go :: forall a1. Int -> [a1] -> Int
    • In the expression: ((take n xs) == (take (n + 1) xs))
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for ‘go’:
        ((take n xs) == (take (n + 1) xs))
      In an equation for ‘go’:
          go n xs
            | ((take n xs) == (take (n + 1) xs)) = n
            | otherwise = go (n + 1) xs
   |
10 |    | ( (take n xs) == (take (n+1) xs) ) = n
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As far as I understood, the reason for the error it that when we try to compare the lists returned from `(take n xs)` and `(take (n+1) xs)`, the compiler does not know the types of lists in advance, so it cannot compare them, and this is why it complains, so before this line, I need to tell the compiler that both return values are the same type, and the type is `[a]`, but how can we do that ?

**A confusion:** when we specify the type signature of `go`, we are explicitly fixing the what is the type of `xs`, i.e so shouldn't the list that is return by the function `take` have the same type, namely `[a]`, hence shouldn't the compiler be able to compare them ?

**Edit:**

Note that, I have another function in the definition of a function, and there are lots of things that are different from the question that is marked as duplicate, and as you can observe, the given answer to that question does not fully solves this question.

Comment: You need to specify that the type `a` is of class `Eq` as well in the signature of `myLength` (as shown [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types#Type_constraints)), otherwise the compiler doesn't know if it can compare `[a]`.

Comment: @hnefatl Thanks for your comment, however, I'm new to Haskell, so I do not know how to do that, can you post s little example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of \`=='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154592/haskell-no-instance-for-eq-a-arising-from-a-use-of)

Comment: @hnefatl I totally understood your argument, but from my point of view, should any list of type [a] be comparable ? I mean I cannot think any type `a` whose such that we cannot compare the values of that type. Is there any such type on top of your head right now ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas `[Integer->Bool]` must not be of class `Eq`, since we can't decide whether two functions are the same in finite time.

Comment: As a general thumb rule, try to use pattern matching before anything else. A function on lists is often defined with `foo [] = ... ; foo (x:xs) = ...` where in the latter case we recurse as `foo xs`. Your approach to find the length is way more complex than needed, and even less general. You can also follow some [tutorial on pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching)

Comment: @chi Thanks for your helpful comments, actually, I haven't even studied pattern matching yet, and I know my solution is not efficient nor elegant, but just trying to use the things that I have learned, and get use the functional programming paradigm for the time being, but I will try to find another solution with that structure as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is instance contexts (here `Eq a`), which is indicated by `=>`:

```
myLength :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
myLength [] = 0
myLength ys = go 1 ys
 where
  go :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> Int
  go n xs
   | ( (take n xs) == (take (n+1) xs) ) = n
   | otherwise = go (n+1) xs
```

But this is not a proper answer to the question #4, because it adds an additional constraint to the function.

**EDIT**: For the question **"Shouldn't every list be equality comparable?"**:
Lists are comparable iff their elements are comparable. For example, functions, `Kleisli` arrows, `WrappedArrow`s are not equality comparable, so aren't lists of them.

Comment: But the code you have provided still gives the same error ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Ah, sorry, `go` must be also contexted the same.

Comment: You should have `{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}` at the very top and write `myLength :: forall a. Eq a => [a] -> Int`. Otherwise `a` in `myLength` and `a` in `go` refer to completely different types

Comment: Ok, now it works, but shouldn't the compiler pass the info that `a` is a is of class `Eq` to `go` function ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas You explicitly specified `go`'s instance context to be none, so it is.

Comment: @DannyuNDos I have specified only that `go` is going to be fed with `[a]` where what is `a` is going to be determined by what is fed with `myLength` where I have specified that the parameter is of class `Eq` ?

Comment: @Iceland_jack That does not work, I mean the compiler also suggested that, but it still gives error with that.

Comment: @Iceland_jack After reading your comment third time, I guess I have misunderstood what you mean, so can you provide an example, just to be clear.

Comment: @onurcanbektas The type parameter `a` in `go`'s type signature is independent from `myLength`'s. (Try substituting `go`'s `a` to `b` and it will be clear.)

Comment: GHC doesn't suggest `ScopedTypeVariables` so I doubt it. I created another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49209220/165806

Answer (score 1):

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

myLength :: forall a. Eq a => [a] -> Int
myLength [] = 0
myLength ys = go 1 ys
 where

  go :: Int -> [a] -> Int
  go n xs
   | take n xs == take (n+1) xs = n
   | otherwise = go (n+1) xs
```

Comment: @onurcanbektas Here, `go`'s `a` is same as `myLength`'s, because of the `forall a`. (I don't know a thing about `ScopedTypeVariables`, though.)

Comment: It throws the error `Illegal symbol '.' in type
    Perhaps you intended to use RankNTypes or a similar language
    extension to enable explicit-forall syntax: forall <tvs>. <type>`.

Comment: @DannyuNDos that `forall .` thing does not work, I mean the compiler also suggested it for several times.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Note the `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypedVariables #-}`. Using that along with the `forall a.` means the `a` in the `go` signature is the same as the one in the `myLength` signature. Also I believe `LANGUAGE` needs to be all caps unlike what has been written here.

Comment: `Language` is fine, “case is ignored” per [user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Actually, `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypedVariables #-}` is not read by ghci. I mean at least I couldn't make it work.

Comment: For ghci you need to run `ghci> :set -XScopedTypeVariables`, I was posting a `.hs` file